# How to recode SYSTEM missing values from nan to empty space while saving SPSS system (sav) files from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, spss

I use savReaderWriter module to save an SPSS file from python pandas dataframe with the following code:

```
import savReaderWriter as srw
savFileName = 'Outfile name.sav'

records = map(list, df.values)

varNames = list(df.columns)
varTypes = {}

for n, values in enumerate(records[0]):
  varName = varNames[n]
  if df.dtypes[n] == 'float64':
      varTypes[varName] = 0
  else:
      varTypes[varName] = 255

with srw.SavWriter(savFileName, varNames, varTypes, ioUtf8=True) as writer:
    writer.writerows(records)
```

The problem is that empty string variables in the SPSS file have "nan" values. 
In the documentation default option for savWriter is **missingValues=None**, but changing the "None" to '' or any other string doesn't do the job. 
What would be solution to have empty string instead of nan?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if you want to represent "nan" values as empty strings the best way is replace them in the source df

```
df.fillna('')
```

and save after that.

P.S. But please take note of the approach which SPSS uses to work with missing data. These settings are in a file's header.

Comment: This is an approach that I already tried, but the side effect is that  all numeric variables with at least one missing value become string. Thank you

Comment: @ibarant So you don't need to use emty strings as values for missing data. You need to describe these values in the header of your exported SPSS file.

Comment: What would be the syntax for that? I found header options for reading SPSS files, but not for writing. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @ibarant In the doc (http://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/generated_api_documentation.html) you can see a parameter - missingValues : dict, optional
missing values dictionary {varName: {missing value spec}}. Cf. MISSING VALUES. See also under savReaderWriter.Header.missingValues().

And there is an explanation here - http://pythonhosted.org/savReaderWriter/generated_api_documentation.html#savReaderWriter.Header.missingValues

Comment: We are talking about different things. Sorry, I did not specify that in the question, but I need to set up SYSTEM MISSING VALUES, not missing values that could be different for different variables. Like for SavReader there is an option to set up recodeSysmisTo=None etc., but that doesn't exist for SavWriter.

Comment: @ibarant Please clarify - do you want to export to csv empty string in number fields in place of NaN? And types of number fields must remain unchanged?

Comment: I do not export to csv. My goal is to create SPSS (.sav) files from csv. I only wanted to set system missing values in SPSS files not like nan. I actually finished the project and recoded all missing values to 999 and then created a missingValues dictionary with values {"values" :[999]}. I just don't understand that SPSS's SYSTEM MISSING is not mentioned in the savWriter while it exists in savReader. Everything is working fine and thank you very much for your support.

Comment: @ibarant it was the right way (exactly what I meant). Good luck! :)